# How do I unlock new workout environments?

Tags: my-fitness-coach

In My Fitness Coach, you start out with a few different workout locations, and the rest are locked.

How do I unlock them? Is it number of workouts? Do those workouts have to be on the days that I have "planned" them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the game manual, you have to work out a certain amount of times on consecutive scheduled days:

> - 3 days -> Bronze level -> Desert Spring Resort -> Dance music
> - 5 days -> Silver level -> Alpine Retreat -> Techno music
> - 7 days -> Gold level -> Island Paradise -> House music
> - 9 days -> Platinum level -> Forest Glade
> - 11 days -> Diamond level -> Rooftop Vista
>
> For example, if you want to reach Silver level, you have to stick to the calendar during 8 days, three from Bronze level plus five to achieve Silver level.